# Store & Retrieve Database entries to Titanium Cloud

Tags: database, sqlite, cloud, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am a bit confuse about Titanium Cloud, please help me out here. 
Suppose a database table have 10 rows in a table. I want to store these rows to [Titanium Cloud](http://docs.appcelerator.com/cloud/latest/#!/guide/titanium) and than also retrieve and update it into database. What should be the proper way to store & retrieve my database entries to Titanium Cloud? I looked into the [API Documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/cloud/latest/#!/api) but there is no object regarding database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remember everything that is stored is stored in a database which Appcelerator handles. 
Now for your requirement. You want to store rows of a table in database. You can do that with [Custom Object](http://docs.appcelerator.com/cloud/latest/#!/api/CustomObjects-method-create)

And for a particular table you can specify a particular class_name to know that these rows belong to that particular table. I hope that will help you. And It should solve your issue. Let me know if that helps you.

Comment: IF this gives the answer of your question please mark it as correct so that others could get help from this. Thanks